# Cheerio's first().text() returns empty value when applied on an HTML input tag with id

Tags: node.js, typescript, web-scraping, cheerio

I am trying to access data from a HTML file's `input` tag using Cheerio. I am able to load the html in cheerio, as well as access the tag's data using `first()`. However, when I try to convert the returned value from `first()` using `text()`, I get a blank return value. The sample html input tag  when obtained, looks like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="abc" id="abc" value="[
   {
      &quot;Status&quot;: &quot;Obtained&quot;,
      &quot;History&quot;: [
        {
           &quot;HistoryDate&quot;: &quot;07/21/2022&quot;
        }
      ]
  }
]" />
```

Below is a sample code that gives me data from the `input` tag whose `id` is "abc".

```
import * as cheerio from 'cheerio';

const $ = cheerio.load(html);
console.log($('#abc').first())
```

However, when I try to convert the above logged value to a text, by using the following, I get a blank value:

```
console.log($('#abc').first().text())
```

Comment: You want `.val()` not `.text()`. `<p this-is-an-attribute="this is a value of an attribute">this is text</p>`.

Comment: Thank you, @ggorlen! That worked! I am pretty new to web-scraping.